# contact form coming error in magento 1.8.1 how to solve?

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

we are new in magneto and facing problem issue my contact us page not working when fill form and submit then coming error 'unable to submit your request. please try again later' what do I do? kindly help me. link
 http://under555.com/contact_us

Answer (score 1):

The contacts form submit to this controller,

```
app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php
```

this will like,

```
public function postAction()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if ( $post ) {
            $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
            /* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
            $translate->setTranslateInline(false);
            try {
                $postObject = new Varien_Object();
                $postObject->setData($post);

                $error = false;

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if ($error) {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
                $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
                /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
                $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                    ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                    ->sendTransactional(
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
                        null,
                        array('data' => $postObject)
                    );

                if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
                    throw new Exception();
                }

                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');

                return;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            }
```

Here you can the error message at last. so 
go and check this file so that you can find where is the problem. Mostly this error caused by the `hideit` input field. You may enable validation for this field in same file

```
if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }
```

if you find this one just comment it out or replace with below one,

```
if (Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }
```

That's it. If you have any doubt please comment here.

Comment: Dear Elavarasan i use this code but not working i thing this problem is SMTP because same code working on unother sever http://kanishkaevents.in/test1/

Comment: oh.! Then it could be mail server issue .

Answer (score 0):

**First thing, which would probably solve the problem, was to change following function of**

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php copy to

app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php



public function setReplyTo($email)
    {
        $this->getMail()->addHeader('Reply-To', $email);
        return $this;
    }
```

to

```
public function setReplyTo($email)
    {
        $this->getMail()->setReplyTo($email);
        return $this;
    }
```

[More info](http://inchoo.net/magento/problems-with-contact-form/)

**[Or](http://php.quicoto.com/how-to-fix-unable-to-submit-your-request-please-try-again-later-contact-form/)**

```
app/design/frontend/YOUR_THEME/template/contacts/form.phtml

Add this after the <form> tag:
<input type="text" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" style="display:none !important;" />
```

Comment: Dear Ravi i use this code but not working i thing this problem is SMTP because same code working on unother sever http://kanishkaevents.in/test1/